# Determinar si es flotamte decimal o caracter

Tags: python

Tengo que determinar si es numero o caracter y si lo es, retornar el numero asoluto de lo conntrario, retornar `no es un valor numerico`.
Cuando determino si es numero  creo que funciona, pero no he podido determinar si es caracter.
PD.Paciencia con mi ignoracia por favor soy nueva en python.

> Write a python program that will detect if the input is an integer, float or a string.  If the input is an integer or float, it should print the absolute value of the input. Else, it should return `It is not a number`.

```
def valid ():
    global value
    if value.isnumeric()or value.find('.') :
        absolute_value = float(value)
        absolute_value = abs(absolute_value)
        print(f" The abosulte Value is:{absolute_value}")
    else: 
        print("It is not a number") 

value = input('Enter a Value')
 
valid()
```

Comment: Depende si quieres validar como carácter solo un cadena alfabética o alfanumérica y para este caso puedes usar el método `.isalnum()`

Comment: Otro caso: Supongamos que tienes esta entrada ```s='2'```, si haces ```eval(s)+0``` y no te da error, es porque la entrada es un numero como string, pero si tuvieses ```s='d2'```, la evaluacion de ```eval(s)+0``` te hubiera dado error.

Comment: Usar eval no es recomendado si la fuente de la cadena no es de confianza (como es el cado ahora). Pues el usuario podria escribir un comando de Python y este se ejecutaria. En su lugar es mejor usar literal_eval del modulo ast.

Comment: ¿Debemos determinar si la cadena contiene solo numero, o es un string o solo un char? o ¿debemos determinar el tipo de dato real: `print(isnstance(1,int));`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma de probar el contenido de un string es intentando convertirlo y ver si falla a no. Para esto se encierra la conversión en un bloque `try-except`, capturando la excepción `ValueError

```
try:
    valor = int(algun_input)
except ValueError:
    print("No es numérico")
```

Con eso, la función queda así:

```
def valid(value):
    valor = None
    try:
        valor = abs(int(value))
    except ValueError:
        try:
            valor = abs(float(value))
        except ValueError:
            print("It is not a number")

    if valor is not None:
        print(f" The absolute Value is:{valor}")
```

Primero intento convertir a entero usando `int`. Si eso falla, puede ser porque es un punto flotante o no es un número. Por tanto, dentro del `except` intento convertirlo con `float`. Si eso también falla, tendrá que ser un string.

De paso, no es recomendable usar variables globales para pasar valores a funciones. Para eso las funciones tienen parámetros.

La práctica estándar es inicializar con `None` las variables que vas a usar dentro del código. El uso de `None` indica que la variable no tiene un valor válido todavía, como es el caso al entrar a validar.

#### Demo

```
def valid(value):
    valor = None
    try:
        valor = abs(int(value))
    except ValueError:
        try:
            valor = abs(float(value))
        except ValueError:
            print("It is not a number")

    if valor is not None:
        print(f" The absolute Value is:{valor}")


while True:
    value = input('Enter a Value ')
    valid(value)
```

produce:

```
Enter a Value 1
 The absolute Value is:1
Enter a Value 2.4
 The absolute Value is:2.4
Enter a Value tra
It is not a number
Enter a Value 
...
```

Comment: Te faltó la función para obtener el valor absoluto(abs()): print(f" The absolute Value is:{abs(valor)}")

Comment: @tincopasan. Cierto. Edite la respuesta.

Comment: Solo faltariá determinar si es un caracter o un string, se puede hacer usando la funcion `len`, si  retorna 0 entonces una cadena vacia, si retorna 1 es un caracter, si retorna mas de 1 entonces es un string.

Comment: @DanielBriceño. En Python son todos strings. No existe el tipo de datos `char`. En otros lenguajes, como C, el `char` y un string ASCIIZ son cosas distintas, pero no en Python.